# Can you create more than one level of nested timeline cards on Glass?

Tags: google-mirror-api

If I create a top level timeline card I can create a single level of nested cards by giving them the same bundleId as the parent.

Can I create a second level of nesting?

```
Top level timelineItem
   - 1st level child timelineItem
   - 1st level child timelineItem
      - 2nd level child timelineItem
      - 2nd level child timelineItem
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. That's not a feature supported by the Mirror API right now.

If you're interested in doing this, I recommend you file an enhancement request on the API [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/list).